# find the principle part of Laurent expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, laurent-series

Find the principle part of the Laurent expansion of the function $f(z) = \frac{1}{(e^z - 1)^2}$ about $z = 0$.
Hint: First show that $f$ has a pole of order $2$ at $z = 0$.

I already found the pole of order $2$ using Laurent expansion. But I am not able to proceed further with finding the principle part.

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand how they went from $\frac{1}{z^2(1+z+...)}$ to $\frac{1}{z^2}(1-z+z^3+...)$

Comment: Just "cut" the series $\;1+z+z^2+\ldots\;$ at $\;1+z\;$ , so you have $\;\frac1{1+z}=1-z+z^2-\ldots\;$ ,  a geometric series development. We can do that because we're working with $\;z\;$ very close to zero. By the way, thanks for the question: I just corrected a typo I had there...:)

Comment: $g(z) = f(z) z^2$ is analytic at $z=0$, all you need is to compute its first few derivatives. Since $e^z-1 \sim z$ you get $z^2 f(z) \sim 1$ and $g(0) = 1$. Then do the same with $g'(z)$ and $g''(z)$